# SIGSEGV Error on Plotting Tubes

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, crash, warning-messages

I have code to plot some "2 dimensional" points in 3D space, and connect a line between them (because ListLinePlot3D takes way to long/hangs), which works fine:

```
Style[Show[
ListPointPlot3D[xyz, PlotRange -> {{420, 460}, {-1, 1}, {0, 10}}], Graphics3D[Line[xyz]]], 
Antialiasing -> False]
```

[image: Graph]

However, each time, when I change Line to Tube Mathematica crashes. WHY?

Here is the error message:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vltp91syb8adcw2/Error.txt?dl=0

Comment: Can you post the data set you use?

Comment: @rcollyer https://www.dropbox.com/s/sq9f5iikh3cw8wd/xyz.csv?dl=0

Comment: many of your data values are fractions, which become strings on a simple `Import`.  Try doing `N@ToExpression@xyz`.   ( I don't get a with your code crash , but I do get an error that some values are non numeric )

Comment: @george2079 That doesn't seem to be a problem....because it works for Line[], and when I try that N@ToExpression@xyz I get: ToExpression::esntx: Could not parse 64/25 as input. >> etc.
FYI this is the data I'm directly graphing after manipulating the previously imported data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I reproduced the crash ( v10/Linux).   You have a huge amout of data almost all of which is out of the plot range.  Try `Select` ing only the required points:

```
 xyz = N@ToExpression[Import["xyz.csv"]];
 Length@xyz  (* 150000 *)
 Length@Select[ xyz , 300 < #[[1]] < 600 & ] (* 117 *)
```

Now this works.

```
 Style[Show[
      ListPointPlot3D[Select[ xyz , 300 < #[[1]] < 600 & ], 
      PlotRange -> {{420, 460}, {-1, 1}, {0, 10}}], 
      Graphics3D[Tube[Select[ xyz , 300 < #[[1]] < 600 & ]]]], 
      Antialiasing -> False]
```

[image]

Note it doesn't look like a "tube" because of the aspect ratio of the plot, but that's a different question